# DNA Features of Genealogy Software

Tags: dna, software-recommendations

Have any traditional genealogy software programs that people use for recording their genealogy research added any features to support DNA research?

I know there are [a lot of DNA utility programs](http://www.gensoftreviews.com/index.php?s=dna&type=util) out there, but I'm more interested in features that have been added to what could be your main genealogy software for recording your information. This will include desktop programs and online family tree programs.

Examples of some features might be the ability to [record DNA data](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/333/what-dna-data-is-important-to-record) for any individual, provide autosomal percentages between people, indicate Y-DNA or mt-DNA candidates for your ancestors, or anything else that might be of use.

Comment: Looks like 5 Programs support it out of the box.

Comment: @Sam - Hmm. They all seem to just be recording the data. Other than what SecondSite does, and possibly the RootsMagic search, none seem to make any use of all that data.

Comment: Good read http://www.beholdgenealogy.com/blog/?p=1627

Answer (score 2):

The [RootsMagic blog says](http://blog.rootsmagic.com/?p=154) RootsMagic (Version 4+) allows to enter Haplogroup, testing company, testing lab, test kit number,... for Y-DNA and mt-DNA.

You can also search for people based on genetic lines (mtDNA, Y-Str)

[According to the ISOGG Wiki, it supports](http://isogg.org/wiki/RootsMagic#DNA_Data) these major testing companies

> - AfricanAncestry
> - AncestryDNA
> - DNAConsultants
> - DNA-Fingerprint
> - DNA Heritage
> - Family Tree DNA
> - Genebase
> - Genelex
> - Genographic Project
> - iGENEA
> - ISFG
> - Oxford Ancestors
> - RootsForReal
> - Sorenson Molecular Genealogy Foundation

Example entry screen (as seen on the ISOGG Wiki):

[image: Enter Y-STR data]

Comment: How does RM use and display this data and make it useful to the user?

Comment: @sam - I did an hour ago. It needs more approvals from other users with enough rep points to do so.

Comment: @sam I have made some further edits to make it more clear where the information in your edits come from.  When you copy from other sites please give proper attribution.

Comment: @JanMurphy - How in RootsMagic do they do the search for people based on genetic lines? That could be a useful feature. Could you give more information on that?

Answer (score 2):

[Legacy Family Tree (Deluxe Edition)](https://www.legacyfamilytree.com/DeluxeEdition.asp) supports recording DNA marker test results from several different companies and can print DNA charts

Some of the [DNA test](http://news.legacyfamilytree.com/legacy_news/2008/12/new-dna-tests-added-to-legacy-family-tree.html) you can record are:

- Ancestry's Paternal Lineage Test (Y-Chromosome 33)
- Ancestry's Advanced Paternal Lineage Test (Y-Chromosome 46)
- DNA Tribes 15-Marker Standard Kit test
- DNA Tribes 21-Marker Premium Kit test
- FamilyTree DNA Y-DNA59 59 Marker Test
- [FamilyTree DNA Y-DNA67 67 Marker Test](http://news.legacyfamilytree.com/legacy_news/2006/05/legacy_update_n_1.html)
- [GeneTree.com Y-DNA 46-marker test](http://news.legacyfamilytree.com/legacy_news/2011/07/legacy-family-tree-update-available-version-75098-adds-mtdna-support.html)
- Oxford Ancestors Y Clan analysis 15-marker test

How to record a DNA test

- Start Legacy and open the Individual's Information screen for the person of interest.
- Click on the DNA button.
- In the Available Tests section, highlight the desired test and click on the Add button.
- Record the results in the table.

[image: DNA button shown]

Comment: @lkessler Someone who has purchased the Deluxe Edition will need to chime in.

Comment: It's strange that Legacy seems to be working so hard to hide these features. You'd think with the interest now in DNA, that they'd be promoting them better.

Answer (score 2):

In the Swedish genealogy software [Genney](https://genny.se), you can add dna samples and haplogroups for Y-DNA and mtDNA. If you add a haplogroup to a person it will forward to all who inherit the haplogroup. It also has a conflict management system that manages conflicts between haplogroups. Haplogroup information is available in person boxes as text and with a green dot for Y-DNA and a pink for mtDNA.

Genney can be used with English interface but the website is currently only in Swedish. Genney can be used on both Windows, Mac OS and Linux.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The discontinued program [TMG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Master_Genealogist)(Version [6](http://www.whollygenes.com/forums201/index.php?/topic/3993-the-master-genealogist-v600-released/) to 9) supported DNA information and had templates to record DNA Fingerprint test kit data for 18 test from 5 companies:

- [DNA Ancestry](http://dna.ancestry.com/) Y-DNA (33 / 46 / 23 / 43) Marker Test
- [Ethnoancestry](http://www.ethnoancestry.com/products.htm) (R 1b Subgroup Y-SNP Test / 27 Marker Test)
- [FamilyTreeDNA](http://www.familytreedna.com/products.aspx) Y-DNA (12 / 25 / 37 / 59 / 67 / 111 ) Marker Test
- [mtDNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrial_DNA) Test (rCRS / RSRS)
- [Relative Genetics](http://www.relativegenetics.com/) Marker Test (18 / 26 / 43 / 43(Revised))

You can access the DNA log from the TMG menu "Tools > DNA log" or via keyboard shortcut (Control + F11)

[image: tmg9.05dnafingerprint-example]

The third party tool [Second Site](http://ss.johncardinal.com/chartdna.htm) can display TMG's DNA data in chart form for comparison (Very good [chart](http://ss.johncardinal.com/demo/dnaoverlaycharts.htm)).

Second Site also can display [Y-DNA data in a grid](http://ss.johncardinal.com/demo/dnagrid.htm):
[image]

[RootsMagic](http://files.rootsmagic.com/TMGDoc.pdf) states that "DNA tests will be imported from TMG, but the actual markers are not mapped to the markers in RM. The markers will be imported into the note for the DNA test"

Comment: TMG is discontinued...

Comment: @Sam - I was very impressed when I followed your link to Second Site and saw what they did to put the Y-DNA Test Results analysis together. John Cardinal acknowledged the help of two respected DNA experts, Alvy Ray Smith and Robert Charles Anderson to help him ensure he was doing it right.

Comment: But I really wonder how many people over the years actually used the DNA capabilities of TMG and Second Site to anywhere near their full extent. And if so, was it all data entry but little gain, or did it provide anything useful for them?

Answer (score 1):

[Family Tree Maker](http://forums.familytreedna.com/showthread.php?t=34262) supports adding DNA info.

Do the following to record your DNA information in Family Tree Maker:

1. If you do not already have your DNA information, you can order a simple test (such as from DNA Ancestry at http://dna.ancestry.com).
2. Add the DNA fact to your list of facts in the Person tab on the People workspace by clicking the Add fact button , choosing the DNA fact, and then clicking OK.
3. Enter the date your DNA was tested in the DNA date field in the right panel.
4. Enter the haplogroup in the DNA description field.
5. Attach any other documentation (such as your DNA test results report) to the DNA media tab in the right panel.

Answer (score 1):

[Family Tree Builder (from MyHeritage)](http://blog.myheritage.com/2010/12/introducing-family-tree-builder-5-0/) allow you to enter DNA Markers.

> DNA Markers: There’s a comprehensive and encrypted new area for
>   entering results from genealogy DNA tests.

[image: DNA markers]

Comment: So far, MyHeritage works only with FamilyTreeDNA who they became partners with in 2009. It appears you can use FTB to extract and record your FamilyTreeDNA information, but the program does not do anything with it yet. It would be exciting if MyHeritage has plans in the future to make their SuperSearch also search for DNA matches.

Answer (score 1):

**My Family Tree**(Chronoplex Software) lets you store [genetic](https://chronoplexsoftware.com/myfamilytree/help/genetics.htm) information.

[image: Edit Genetics panel - from **My Family Tree**]

Edit Genetics panel - from **My Family Tree**

Answer (score -2):

You may want to take a look at the free program Genome Mate Pro.  It is critical for my analysis of autosomal DNA match results from the three major testing companies in one place.

Comment: But it is not Genealogy Software as asked for by the question.